# Error Ops.POSXt when calling a function inside the main function; outside call test running fine

Tags: r

I'm building some personal packages in R in a windows 10 pro machine.
I'm running one package that is a collection of single functions, with a main function that calls what is needed.
I'm experiencing the `Error Ops.POSIXt(left, right) : '&' not defined for POSIXt objects` error when the execution comes up calling the `comp_hc_forz_front` function.

This function should add a column to a dataframe, when called by the main function.
I tried to export the dataframe to the global environment just before this call, and the dataframe is ok.

Furthermore if I try to call the `comp_hc_forz_front` function in the global environment everything works fine and I get the new column with all the values calculated.

This is the function

```
comp_hc_forz_front <- function(n_reynolds=NULL, k_air=NULL, height_modulo=1, width_modulo=1) {

  sup_modulo <- height_modulo*width_modulo
  Lc <- sup_modulo / (2*(height_modulo+width_modulo))

  value <- k_air/Lc * (2+0.41*(n_reynolds^0.55)) * sup_modulo

  return(value)

}
```

This is the call inside the main function that doesn't complete

```
db$hc_forz_front <- comp_hc_forz_front(n_reynolds=db$n_reynolds, k_air=db&k_air, height_modulo=height_modulo, width_modulo=width_modulo)
```

I didn't find much online and I'm not able to understand the link between the POSIXt and a function adding some values to a dataframe.
I checked the dataframe and all the input data are confirmed to be double.

Why is the function working outside the main function and not during the main simulation, and what is this error about?

Thank you in advance

I double checked the functions, rebuilt the package, performed the calculation in a for loop passing each value of the vectors. I got the error anyway.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to perform a logical operation on a date object. Without the code that produces the error it's difficult to say much more. Have you tried debugging it yourself?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I added the code hoping that this will help. I'm not operating on date objects, this is why I have no idea about what's going on. I tried to rebuild the package with another machine, but running I got the same results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a typo in your code, an errant ampersand:

```
db$hc_forz_front <- comp_hc_forz_front(n_reynolds=db$n_reynolds, k_air=db&k_air
_________________________________________________________________________^
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and effort. I was completely blind to the typo!

Comment: @BigF: Sometimes you just need an extra set of eyes on the problem